# How to make a per-server, changeable prefix for a Discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm working on an Economy Bot for Discord written in Node.js with the Discord.js library. I am wondering on how I, and others, could make a per-server, changeable prefix. For example, I would run the command: !changeprefix (new prefix)

I've already tried to use Enmap to create a per-server configuration, but then it would give me unknown errors that made no sense at all.

```
exports.run = (client, message) => {
     if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'))
        message.reply(Sorry, you don't have enough perms.)


    //(The rest of the code that I do not know how to do)
}
```

My current code only lets Admins run it. I only want Admins to run it.

Comment: You can save the prefix in an associative array(key=guild id, value=prefix)
If there is no entry in the array you can use the default prefix.
After a change you should write the array to a file that will be loaded at the beginning.

Comment: The `discord.js-commando` library has a built in command to do that. In `discord.js` you can store the prefix in a guild.id-prefix object/map; then, instead of checking for the global prefix only, you check for `(prefix == prefixForTheGuild || (prefix == globalPrefix && !prefixForTheGuild))`

Comment: Thank you @FedericoGrandi. I shall try that. I've tried to use a similar method, but it didn't work, so I'll try this one.